# Saving all files generated by compiler in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I am currently developing a compiler plugin for a domain-specific language (DSL) that I wrote in Scala. As a result, I have one "examples" directory (SBT subproject) in my repo that contains a sample program written using the DSL. I can compile this subproject fine, and it works as expected.

My plugin analyzes this sample program and produces an output file (generated by simply writing out to a file). I have created a new subproject for the same "examples" directory. It has special command line options that instruct the compiler to use the plugin. Everything runs fine, but despite numerous searches, I haven't been able to figure out where the output file is generated. I suspect that it is being tossed.

Below is my `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.bitbucket.bitstream-dsl",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    name := "example-project"
  )

lazy val examples = (project in file("examples"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    name := "examples"
  )
  .dependsOn(root)

lazy val examplesPlugin = (project in file("examples"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    scalacOptions += "-Xplugin:plugin/target/scala-2.12/plugin_2.12-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar",
    name := "examples_plugin",
    target := baseDirectory.value / "target-plugin",
    publishArtifact in Compile := true
  )
  .dependsOn(root)

lazy val plugin = (project in file("plugin"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    scalacOptions += "-J-Xss256m",
    name := "plugin",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
  )
  .dependsOn(root)

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
```

Here is how I am writing out to a file:

```
def printFile(funcBody: String) : Unit = {
  // open a file to be written
  val file = new File("test.v")
  val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
  bw.write(funcBody + "\n")

  //close the output file
  bw.close() 
}
```

Comment: what is the code for "generated by simply writing out to a file"?

Comment: I added a new code section at the bottom of my question addressing this

Comment: after the `val file = ...` line, add `println(file.getCanonicalPath)` to see where it ended up

Comment: That would work if I was manually testing the compiler plugin but SBT seems to suppress any console output from the plugin.

Comment: maybe sbt's `last` command would help with that?